# get current latitude , longitude and display my current location with google map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

```
var googleMap;
var myLatitude, myLongitude;
 var scriptTag=$('<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myAPIKEY(I don\'t want to show it)&callback=myMap"></script>');
 (function($){

if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        myLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        myLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
    });
}else{
    $('section#Map').html('Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation');
}$('body').append(scriptTag);
 }(jQuery));

 function myMap(){
console.log(myLatitude);
var googleMap = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatitude,myLongitude),
    zoom:8
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('Map'),googleMap);
 }
```

I am using this code to get current latitude and longitude and show my current

location with google map api.

I tested my code with alert and console.log and saw function myMap triggers

before geolocation.getCurrentPosition(maybe bacause brwoser waits until user gives feedback. I am not sure)

and I get latitude, longitude as undefined. I tried to move navigator code

inside myMap function but didn't work. How should I do?

Comment: Indeed, `getCurrentPosition` wait for the user input before registering the Lat/Lng. That's why the function accepts a callback as argument. You should centre the map after the it has been loaded **and** the user has accepted to share his position (inside the callback function).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks, I made a callback which appends google map api and called that as callback inside if loop and worked!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!
After posting question, I found getCurrentPosition runs asynchronously.

I just created function which adds script tag into body and made that

as callback

```
function($){
   if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)){
               addScript();
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
function addScript(){
    $('body').append('<script src="link of API"></script>');
}
```